# Is min-width with autowidth:true incompatible?

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid with the following parameters:

```
autowidth: true,
shrinkToFit: true
```

I have a table (with 23 columns) with 100% width.

I want to implement a min-width of 1400px but it doesn't work with autowidth and shrinkToFit set to true.

I tried:
`$("#list").jqGrid('gridResize', { minWidth: 1400 });`

and CSS:

`ui-jqgrid {min-width: 1400px;}`
or 
`table {min-width: 1400px;}`

But nothing works.
When I re-size the browser under 1400px the table columns become too narrow and the columns set with `fixed: true` instead increase in width.

Comment: Probably the best workaround would be to set `autowidth:false, width:1400,` automatically when the resolution is =< 1400px. But how could I do to automate it? into loadComplete?